# How can this problem be resolved for angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstarp/dist/css/bootstarp.min.css ./node_modules/bootstarp/dist/css/bootstarp-theme.min.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\SURO\Documents\angular\first-web-app\node_modules\bootstarp\dist\css\bootstarp-theme.min.css' in 'C:\Users\SURO\Documents\angular\first-web-app'
ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstarp/dist/css/bootstarp.min.css ./node_modules/bootstarp/dist/css/bootstarp-theme.min.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\SURO\Documents\angular\first-web-app\node_modules\bootstarp\dist\css\bootstarp.min.css' in 'C:\Users\SURO\Documents\angular\first-web-app'
```

Comment: how did you add bootstrap? also seems the name is wrong. should be bootstrap

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, have a tour on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can you please add the code inside you package.json and angular.json files?

Comment: My mistakes! sorry. I guess I misspelled it

Comment: I removed it from angular.json and import in the style.css by using @import, now it's working fine